# Initialise two variables to point to same reference in Python

Tags: python, pointers, variables

I have seen many similar questions here, but none of them deal with what I want to know. Let's take an example.

I want to make a linked list from an array. Ignoring all the boilerplate, let's get to the meat of this question.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tail = head = None  # this is the problematic line
for item in arr:
  tail = Node(val=item, next=None)
  tail = tail.next
return head
```

Needless to say, this does not work. Head always points to None, no matter what tails points to.

Some other things I have tried:

```
head = tail = [] # head will point to the empty list after finishing
head = tail = any_other_singleton # does not work
```

I know why this happens. Its because I am reassigning tail to point to a Node. But I want to keep a reference to the head of the liked list in 'head'. How can I make this work? In other programming languages this is trivial, but in python you have to assign a value to variable when declaring, which is causing me problems.

Comment: *Python doesn't have pointers*. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is correct but it's still possible to simulate pointer behavour https://onlinegdb.com/bTMmQX56W

Comment: How would you trivially do this in other languages, as you say?

Comment: That's a mistake on my part. I should have clarified not all programming languages, as opposed to what is implied. But I believe in C++, we can have two pointers to the same reference and work on from there, can't we?

Answer (score 1):

Just handle the first item separately.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
head = tail = Node(val=arr[0], next=None)
for item in arr[1:]:
    tail.next = Node(val=item, next=none)
    tail = tail.next
return head
```

Comment: if Node is a namedtuple `tail.next = ...` will not work.

Comment: @Nolan A linked list fundamentally requires being able to modify the `.next` field - that's the entire point of them, being able to insert an element in the middle without having to shift back the rest of the list. If you're using a namedtuple (or other immutable variable) as a node, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What you are saying cannot be further from the truth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Linked_lists

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy well, in Python, generally that would be the case. But a linked list is sort of the canonical example of an immutable data struture in various functional programming languages, often called "cons lists" in that context, after the "cons" operation in LISP

Answer (score 1):

Could use a dummy *before* the real list. That won't crash if `arr` is empty.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tail = dummy = Node(val=None, next=None)
for val in arr:
    tail.next = tail = Node(val=val, next=None)
return dummy.next
```

Not tested, due to missing `Node` class.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can probably be done like this.

```
from collections import namedtuple


Node = namedtuple('Node', ['val', 'next'])


def array_to_list(arr):
    lst = None
    for a in reversed(arr):
        lst = Node(val=a, next=lst)
    return lst
    

x = array_to_list([1, 2, 3]) 
print(x)
```

Next code might help with understanding if you never worked with persistent (immutable) data structures:

```
def insert_recursive(lst, pos, value):
    if not pos or not lst:
        return Node(val=value, next=lst)
    return Node(val=lst.val, next=insert_recursive(lst.next, pos - 1, value))
    

def insert_nonrecursive(lst, pos, value):
    values = []
    while lst and pos:
        values.append(lst.val)
        lst = lst.next
        pos -= 1
    result = Node(val=value, next=lst)
    while len(values):
        result = Node(val=values.pop(), next=result)
    return result
    

y = insert_recursive(x, 1, 42)
print(y)

z = insert_nonrecursive(x, 1, 42)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know `functools.reduce` is a bit of black-sheep in the Python world, but it makes a nice one-liner for this if you process the list in reverse. For example:

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple('Node', ['next', 'val']) # or alternatively a class with next, val members
        
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Make Linked List
lst = reduce(Node, reversed(arr), None)

# Try printing them
head = lst
while head:
    print(head.val)
    head = head.next
```

Will print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```